# prove that one of the digits $1,2,\dots,9$ occurs infinitely often in the decimal expansion of $\pi$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

prove that one of the digits $1,2,\ldots,9$ occurs infinitely often in the decimal expansion of $\pi$. you may use without proof the fact that $\pi$ is irrational. It is recommended using proof by contradiction.

**My attempt:**

Supppose that $1$ does not occur infinitely in the decimal expansion of $\pi$ and that it only occurs once.

Since  the starting decimals of $\pi$ is $3.14$ then $1$ has already occurred but since $\pi$ is irrational, the decimal expansion is infinitely long it means that $1$ has to occur in $\pi$ infinitely.

By contradiction $1$ must occur infinitely long in the decimal expansion of $\pi.$

---

**Note:**

I realised my attempt is foiled since one argument to my attempt could be; what if $1$ never occurs again, but $2$ occurs infinitely often?

**Question:**

How do you proof what I am trying to proof by contradiction?

Comment: In fact it is still an open question whether there are infinitely many $1$s in the decimal expansion of $\pi$ (not that anyone seriously believes there are only finitely many, but proving it is not so easy).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\pi$ is irrational, so its decimal expansion does not terminate. But if *every* digit except $0$ occurs only finitely many times...

Comment: "every digit except 0"

Comment: I missed that, thanks. It doesn't matter much though.

Answer (score 5):

If each of the digits $1$ through $9$ occurs only finitely many times, then all of them together occur only finitely many times: the sum of nine finite numbers is finite.  After all of them are done occurring you have only $0$s.  But that cannot happen with an irrational number.