# Hypothetical contradiction to Bolzano-Weierstrass

Tags: limits

we've learned about the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem that states that if a sequence is bounded, then it has a subsequence that converges to a finite limit. 
Let's define $a_n$ as the digits of $\pi$, i.e. $a_1$ = 3, $a_2$ = 1, $a_3$ = 4, and so on infinitely. Certainly this sequence is bounded by 10 and 0, but I can't think of any subsequence that will converge to anything. 
Can you help solve my confusion?

Comment: Just because you can't explicitly give an example does not mean one doesn't exist.

Comment: But, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599217/prove-that-one-of-the-digits-1-2-9-occurs-infinitely-often-in-the-decimal-expa).

Answer (score 17):

Sure, take the subsequence of every occurrence of $1$. If there aren't infinitely many $1$s, then $2$s; if not $2$s then $3$s, etc. As $\pi$ is irrational, at least one non-zero digit in the decimal expansion is repeated infinitely many times.

Comment: This works with every number, it is not required that the number is irrational. The digits can be 0... so some digit will repeat infinitely many times.

Comment: Maybe he was thinking of *two* digits (possibly including 0) occurring infinitely often; then irrationality comes into play.

Comment: It's a matter of convention: I usually think of a decimal expansion as finite "if it's finite", e.g., 1.2, not 1.200000....